Angular sidenav combined with scroll restoration
Currently working on an Angular project that requires to add the ability for scroll position restoration. I have enabled scrollPositionRestoration etc, no problem here. However, as I want a layout with a sidebar to the left, the content to the right and a toolbar spanning the sidenav on top, I have problem on the scrolling functionality. The content inside mat-sidenav-content is scrollable, but the pageYOffset is always 0 as we are not scrolling the page, instead only the content container.
I would like to avoid a lot of custom handling of this, and think that redesign would make more sense. After several attempts to find people with similar issues I turn to Stackoverflow. I would be surprised if this is not a common scenario.
The layout looks like this:
<mat-toolbar>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="menu-button">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="toolbar-logo d-flex">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.png">
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [opened]="opened" [autoFocus]="false">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <app-sidemenu></app-sidemenu>
      </mat-nav-list>
      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="logout()">
          <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

and the scss:
mat-sidenav-container {
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
}

.toolbar-logo img {
  height: 20px;
}

.mat-sidenav {
  width: 220px;
}

Anyone with experience how to both use mat-sidenav-container and scrollPositionRestoration?
